# I want to copy a file but it says not such file or directory

Tags: linux

```
root@kali:-/Desktop# cp new.txt Desktop/new.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already inside of the `Desktop` directory and that directory doesn't contain another directory named `Desktop`.

If you are just trying to make a copy of it in the same directory, you will need to change its name like:

```
cp ~/Desktop/new.txt ~/Desktop/new1.txt
```

Comment: thank you very very much man.I appreciated

Comment: hey i tried it in the root directory to copy it in the desktop directory but it says cp;cannot stat 'new.txt' : No such file or directory

Comment: You need to either use a [full or relative path](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/) for everything

Comment: please can u give me an example coz i cant understand it. sorry

Comment: @RuhejlVojka: I've updated my answer. I also recommend reading the article I linked in my comment about paths

Comment: thank you very much